# bash log file count words and replace them by number

Tags: bash, logging, count, grep

I need to keep warnings from my script log and add a "LAST" to every line after each start so I know when the alert occurs at a glance so I add this to my script :
This is the fist line of my script :

```
echo "$( cat $ALERT_LOG_FILE | grep WARNING | tail -n 2k | ts "LAST ")" > $ALERT_LOG_FILE
```

Script log looks like this at first run :

`WARNING : ...
WARNING : ...
WARNING : ...
WARNING : ...`

When script start/restart the echo line adds "LAST" to each line and make it like this :

`LAST WARNING : ...
LAST WARNING : ...
LAST WARNING : ...
LAST WARNING : ...`

Problem is the log file becomes like this after some restarts:

`LAST LAST LAST LAST WARNING : ....
LAST LAST LAST WARNING : ....
LAST LAST WARNING : ....
LAST LAST WARNING : ....
LAST WARNING : ....
WARNING:`

Any way to make it like this:

`LAST 4 WARNING : ....
LAST 3 WARNING : ....
LAST 2 WARNING : ....
LAST 2 WARNING : ....
LAST 2 WARNING : ....
LAST 1 WARNING : ....
WARNING:`

EDIT:

code with @Yoda suggestion:

```
cat $LOG_FILE | grep WARNING | tail -n 2k  | ts "LAST " | awk '{n=gsub("LAST ",X);if(n) print "LAST",n,$0;else print}')" > $LOG_FILE
```

out put log after some restarts with @Yoda suggestion:

`LAST 2  2  1  WARNING : ...
LAST 2  1  WARNING : ...
LAST 1  WARNING : ...
WARNING : ...`

Comment: What is the `ts` command?

Comment: I believe the command you're looking for is `wc`.

Comment: ts adds the "LAST" to begging of each line

Comment: The idea is to add "LAST" to each "WARNING" line after every start/restart of the script so in a glance you get the restarts and warning from each session

Comment: ts is from "moreutils" package

Answer (score 0):

Based on some assumptions:-

```
$ awk '{n=gsub("LAST ",X);if(n) print "LAST",n,$0;else print}' file
LAST 4 WARNING : ....
LAST 3 WARNING : ....
LAST 2 WARNING : ....
LAST 2 WARNING : ....
LAST 1 WARNING : ....
WARNING:
```

If this is not what your are looking for, then I would suggest posting a representative sample of your log file and expected output.

Comment: Almost there, Thanks The first run is ok
`echo "$(cat $LOG_FILE | grep WARNING | tail -n 2k | ts "LAST " | awk '{n=gsub("LAST ",X);if(n) print "LAST",n,$0;else print}')" > $LOG_FILE`
But 2nd run gives this:    
`LAST 2  2  1  WARNING ...
LAST 2  1  WARNING : ...
LAST 1  WARNING : ...`

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, it was based on some assumptions without knowing how your input log looks like. So post a representative sample of your input log file and expected output. Also post what exactly `ts` does.

Comment: Already edited first post and I think I added all needed, ts is from moreutils package, it adds "LAST" to beginning of each line of log

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that might help:-

```
awk '
        {
                n = gsub("LAST ",X)
                if( n )
                {
                        for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ )
                        {
                                if ( $i ~ /WARNING/ )
                                {
                                        sub(/^ */,X)
                                        print "LAST",n,$0;
                                        next
                                }
                                if ( $i ~ /^[0-9]$/ )
                                {
                                        n += $i
                                        $i = ""
                                }
                        }
                }
                else
                        print $0
        }
'
```